# Files are appending to my list multiple times

Tags: python, list

In my function below `run_check` is a global list. When I append to it below the files get appended as many times as there are files in processing list.

Is there a way to only append the files once to `run_check` if the `if` statement in the third loop is not true?

```
def lookForProcessingFiles(ctf,gcc):
    processingList = []

    for file in os.listdir(Incoming_Data):
        if (file[:32] == ctf[:32]) and (file[:32] == gcc[:32]):
            processingList.append(file)

    for x,y in itertools.combinations(processingList,2):
        if (x[:58] == y[:58]) and x.endswith('.raw') and y.endswith('.csv'):
            #checkDict()
            #move y then move x to input folder       
            print(x,y)

    for file in processingList:
        if (file[:32] == ctf[:32]) and (file[:32] == gcc[:32]) and  file.endswith('last.txt'):
            #checkDict()
            #move file to input
            #remove files from runs_dict
            print('Last: ' + file)

        else:
            #runs_dict.update({'CTF: ' + ctf[8:27]:ctf, 'GCC: ' +gcc[8:27]:gcc})
            run_check.append(ctf)
            run_check.append(gcc)
```

Comment: keep a flag in the loop which tells you if the condition has ever not been true, then append outside the loop based on that flag. But please, in general, you should provide a [mcve].

Comment: just add ```break``` after appends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `any()` to test all the files.

```
if not any(file[:32] == ctf[:32]) and (file[:32] == gcc[:32]) and  file.endswith('last.txt') for file in processingList):
    run_check.append(ctf)
    run_check.append(gcc)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 solutions to this problem

1. Use Set instead of list (fast)
2. Use dict and then do list(dict.keys()) when you need to use them (fast)
   `dict[data] = None`
   `list(dict.keys())`
3. check for value in list before using it. `if _ in list:` (slow)

[Source](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Epattis/ICS-33/lectures/complexitypython.txt)

Comment: Why would be the use of `set` a slow solution?

Comment: That's a very interesting source you shared there.